# How do you load a saved model in ML.NET?

Tags: .net, ml.net

I'm using ML.NET v0.11.0 to create and save a model. The save process seems to work, but I am having difficulty determining how to load that model back in for use.

```
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
IDataView trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(myData);

// Setup and train the model
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label")
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Field1", "Field2"))
        .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext)
        .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features"))
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

var m = pipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);
using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create("mymodel.zip"))
{
    // this works
    mlContext.Model.Save(m, stream);
}

TransformerChain<KeyToValueMappingTransformer> loadedModel;
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("mymodel.zip"))
{
    // this will not work, as ITransformer cannot be cast to TransformerChain<KeyToValueMappingTransformer>
    loadedModel = (TransformerChain<KeyToValueMappingTransformer>)mlContext.Model.Load(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to cast the load. Try taking it off and see if it works. The below works for me with no issues.

```
ITransformer _model;

using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(modelPath))
{
    _model = _context.Model.Load(stream);
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that.. that was it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)